# Update Git Automatically

Tags: git, updates

I've seen a lot of posts about how to update git *repositories*, but I want to know if there's a way to automatically update Git itself.  I frequently instal Git on new computers, and I feel like every time I do there's a new version, so I have to update all the installations on my other machines.  I would like to *always* have the latest version of Git.  Is this possible in Windows?  Perhaps with some kind of batch script?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried this `git submodule update`

Comment: @Ashish  Running that command doesnt yield any output, so I'm not sure if it does anything

Comment: you are talking about repository update or git software update ??

Comment: How many machines are we talking about? 3 or 300? And why do you want *always* and *everywhere* the *latest* version of git ?

Comment: @Ashish I'm talking about Git software update.  I'm talking about just a couple machines, and I want the latest version for the same reason one would want the latest version of Chrome or Office, just to keep things updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through some old questions of mine and just saw this one. The Git for Windows installer now includes an option to check for git updates daily. Not sure which version introduced this, or whether the same option is available on Mac/Linux, but yeah, that's how you check for git updates automatically. :P

Answer (score 1):

You could [install Git via Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/git).

Then you can just run `choco upgrade git` on each machine.

Comment: what exactly is Chocolatey?

Comment: @Rabadash8820 Follow the link in my answer and click on About. They explain it better than I could here.